# Python keyword args vs kwargs

Tags: python, keyword-argument

This might be a simple question:

Is there any difference between the two folowing:

```
def myfunc(a_list = [], **kwargs):
    my_arg = kwargs.get('my_arg', None)
    pass
```

and

```
def myfucn(a_list = [], my_arg = None):
    pass
```

If not, which would be considered more pythonic?

Thanks,
-Matt

Comment: More importantly, never use a mutable default argument (a_list above).  See here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Sidnote: Do not use `[]` as a default argument, as `[]` is mutable. http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html#Default_Argument_Values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a simple function, it's more Pythonic to explicitly define your arguments.  Unless you have a legit requirement to accept any number of unknown or variable arguments, the `**kwargs` method is adding unnecessary complexity.

Bonus: Never initialize a list in the function definition! This can have unexpected results by causing it to persist because lists are mutable!

Answer (score 1):

The first one can take virtually *any* keyword arguments provided (regardless of the fact that it only uses one of them), whereas the second can only take two. Neither is more Pythonic, you simply use the one appropriate for the task.

Also, the second is not "keyword arguments" but rather a "default value".

Answer (score 1):

The second alternative allows my_arg to be passed as a positional rather than a keyword argument.  I would consider it unpythonic to declare `**kwargs` when you don't actually use them for anything.